# parseDate is giving even time value - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have this function to parseDate after the date is being loaded form a csv file which contains `date` in a column.

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(data) {
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;


  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = parseDate(String(d.x));
    d.y = +d.y;
  })
})
```

column `x` contains date in this formar `2013-12-01`. After I import the data the date which is in column `x` is a string. So to convert it to date. I used `data.forEach` as shown in the code above.

But the result I get is this `"2013-11-30T18:30:00.000Z"`.

Some one help me in getting the date in this `2013-12-01` format.

Comment: It would seem that the conversion is taking into account an offset of +05:30. Are you in India or Sri Lanka by chance? I am not familiar with the libraries you mention, but it would appear to be treating `2013-12-01` as `2013-12-01T00:00:00UTC+05:30` which is equivalent to `2013-11-30T18:30:00.000Z`.

Comment: Yes. How would i get rid of it now?

Comment: You mean you just want `'2013-11-30T18:30:00.000Z'.replace(/T.*/,'')`. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. I just need only the date in this format `2013-12-01`. I do not need that `T18:30:00.000Z`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2013-12-01 to be treated as a UTC date, then you can parse it yourself as such:

```
function parseUTC(s) {
    s = s.split(/\D/);
    return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2]));
}

alert( parseUTC('2013-12-01').toUTCString() ); // Sun, 01 Dec 2013 00:00:00 GMT
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry. I need only the date nothing else. In this format `2013-12-01`